# I want to know about the pricing of an app that is running using FIREBASE

Tags: firebase

assume the app is downloaded 10 times and uses the Flame Plan .Does that mean all 10 downloads have their own Flame Plan or the 10 downloads are sharing the  1 Flame Plan? How does it Work ??

Comment: can you please help me get to the right site though

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a cloud Service. If you load your app locally to modify or expand with functionality, you use only one flame plan. No matter how many people work on your project and download it locally, it’s only one flame plan.

For more information read the Pricing Guide of Firebase.

[Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)